# Transform App.Config and App.Release.Config Files In .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-config, app-config, web.config-transform

I am trying to port an old dotnet framekwork 4.8 web application to dotnet core 3.1. This project is one of four project in my solution:

1. dotnet core 3.1 (currently porting from dotnet  framework 4.8 MVC project)
2. dotnet framework 4.8 webforms project (migrating to .net core project)
3. dotnet framework 4.8 class library (for shared code)
4. dotnet framework 4.8 class library (for database)

The code in the existing class library (#3) uses the ConfigurationManager class to access the appsetting section of my app.config file. I can not change this code to take from my appsettings.json file because my dotnet framework webforms project also depends on the class library.

Is it possible to get the same transformation functionality that my old dotnet framework MVC project was doing for the app.config file? I would like to transform the app.config file when I publish and include the app.release.config contents.

Below I included an example of my app.config and app.release.config files. I removed all personal data so pleases let me know if you need clarification.

This is my app config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- connection string here (used by the class libray and requires the file to be named app.config not web.config) -->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="runasUserNoDomain" value="domianVal" />
    <!-- Add More appsetting items here... -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is my app.release.config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<appSettings>
    <add key="website1" value="https://subdomain1.mydomain.com" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="website2" value="https://subdomain2.mydomain.com" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Why use an app.config file? .NET Core has support for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration which can read settings from appsetting.json, and there is an equivalent functionality to app config transformations contained within it.

Comment: @mason & Nkosi Thank you both for your comments. I am using an appsettings.json file and a appsetting.production.json file in my .net core project. The reason I need the app.config file is to support a legacy class library that is running .net framework 4.8 which uses the ConfigurationManager class. I can not remove this dependency and I can not port the class library. I will update my question to be more clear.

Comment: Can you modify the class library to not take a hard dependency on ConfigurationManager? That way you can pass in configuration as needed?

Comment: What keeps you from porting the class library to .NET Core or .NET Standard?

Comment: I just updated my question. My webforms app depends on my class library and has its own web.config file.

Comment: Just because the class library is consumed by .NET Core and .NET Framework doesn't mean you can't change it to not have a dependency on ConfigurationManager. Your class library needs to target .NET Standard, which can be consumed by both. Then remove any dependency on ConfigurationManager. Instead, any configuration the class library needs should be passed into it. It's definitely doable.

Comment: @mason Thanks for the suggestion! By "any configuration the class library needs should be passed into it." Do you mean when we call a method or class from the class library we should pass any config values to it?

Comment: Exactly. Let's say you have a class in your class library called DatabaseRepository. Right now, in the constructor that class might be utilizing ConfigurationManager to obtain a connection string in order to make a database connection. Now that you need to use that class library across .NET Framework and .NET Core, you should modify the constructor of that class to take the connection string in as a parameter. That way the calling application can obtain the connection string via ConfigurationManager or the .NET Core way, and pass it to the constructor.